# Change back button image in all screen of app in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have tried to use below codes but not able to get the result.

```
let backArrowImage = UIImage(named: "backButton")!
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = backArrowImage
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backArrowImage
```

or

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonBackgroundImage(backArrowImage, for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
```

Is there any other thing i have to do ?

Comment: Create a category for that....and call the same method from ViewDidAppear from all your viewcontrollers

Comment: Where are you calling `UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonBackgroundImage(backArrowImage, for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)` ?

Comment: are you embedding a UIButton inside the UIBarButtonItem?

Comment: first rename the image "backButton " to "backButton_old" and then just add the required back button and replace the name with "backButton".

Answer (score 0):

Some Ways which I have using in my Project.

**1)Creating Custom NavigationController :**

```
class CustomNavigationViewController: UINavigationController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "\0x00a0", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

**2) Set in viewDidLoad Or viewWillAppear** : 
// user as you need

```
func configureNavController() {
    self.title = "navTitle"
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = //Color
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = //Color
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false

    if isRootView == true { // Do this if you are in detail view  and want to pop your VC
        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back".localized, style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(backButtonClicked))
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
    }
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.sendButton
}
```